# Battery size and maximal power output

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, battery, microelectronics

Generally how does the size of the battery affect its maximal power output(together with other factors like materials, for instance)?

Under the current engineering technology and with any possible material which is realistic to apply currently, for a battery of tiny size which is rechargeable via electrochemical reactions, how does the size of the battery affect the maximal output **power** of it?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

For any battery which works via electrochemical reactions, the *voltage* output of the battery will be the same regardless of its size as long as the chemistry is the same. However, the *current* output of the battery depends on the square area of the surfaces upon which the chemistry is taking place. Small surfaces, as in small batteries, means small amounts of current.

Furthermore, the net amount of electrical energy that a given battery can furnish over its lifetime is set by the masses of the chemical reactants contained inside the battery which power the chemical reactions that yield electron flow. Small batteries mean small masses, which means a short lifetime and a small amount of net energy delivered.